# Custom SSH Config Not Working

Tags: git, ssh, port

I have been trying to get ssh to connect to Github using port 443 and I have decided to use a custom ssh config file at `~/.ssh/config`. After creating the file and setting the proper file permissions I attempt to connect again, the connection is still timing out on port 22. I know this because port 22 is blocked by my ISP (for some strange reason).

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ touch config
$ chown $USER config
$ chmod 644 config
```

Then in the config file I add this:

```
Host pagodabox.io
  HostName git.pagodabox.io
  Port 443

Host github.com
  HostName ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Then I attempt to call this from my iTerm app.

```
$ ssh -T git@ssh.github.com
```

I get the error:

> ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Operation timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

However, if I do this

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

I get the desired response.

> Hi [Username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I am using oh-my-zsh FWIW. Why is this happening? I have rebooted my mac also. Still the file doesn't seem to be recognised

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You wrote:

```
 Host github.com
   HostName ssh.github.com
   Port 443
```

But didn't use it:

```
 ssh -T git@ssh.github.com
```

You need to

```
 ssh -T git@github.com
```

to use the `github.com` host you defined.

---

Alternatively, add `ssh.github.com` as another name to match:

```
 Host github.com ssh.github.com
   HostName ssh.github.com
   Port 443
```